# pygame: drawing text to Surface before drawing on screen

Tags: python, pygame

There are a lot of these question already, but I can't figure out what's wrong. compounding the problem the code is spread out over a class. I'm trying to create a scrolling panel. This is class slot which displays some phrase, and acts as a linked list to allow growth (and hopefully compact code)

code: 
variables: the_game: instance of module pygame, font: instance of module pygame.font, phrase: string being pushed, self.bitmap: Surface object of slot to be drawn to screen, num: number indicating slot number, because they are supposed to be in sequence.

```
class slot(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,num,dimx,dimy,the_game,font):
        ...
        self.wordnum = convertnum(num)+". "
        self.phrase=""
        self.bitmap = the_game.Surface((dimx,dimy))
        self.updatesprite(the_game,font)
```

function updatesprite for clearing and re-blitting whatever phrase the slot is supposed to hold when changed:

```
    def updatesprite(self,the_game,font):
        self.bitmap.fill((240,240,240))
        phrase = self.wordnum
        if(self.has_phrase==True):
            phrase+=self.phrase
        text = font.render(phrase,1,(0,0,255))
        the_game.Surface.blit(text,self.bitmap,[self.x+2, self.y+2])
    ...
```

for moving back a phrase or sentence onto the next slot when another one is "pushed" on a previous slot

```
    def mypush(self,num,phrase,the_game,font):
        if (num > self.num):
            if (self.has_next==False):
                self.addmore(num-self.num,the_game,font)
            self.next.mypush(num,phrase,the_game,font)
            self.updatesprite(the_game,font)
        elif (num == self.num):
            if (self.has_phrase==True):
                self.mypush(self.num+1,self.phrase,the_game,font)
            else:
                self.has_phrase=True
            self.phrase=phrase
            self.updatesprite(the_game,font)
```

function for setting the phrase of a slot:

```
    def setphrase(self,phrase,realx,realy,virty,realdim,mousex,mousey,the_game,font):
        ...
        if (self.has_phrase==True):
            self.mypush(self.num+1,self.phrase,the_game,font)                
            self.has_phrase=True
        self.phrase=phrase
        self.updatesprite(the_game,font)
```

and then the method for drawing to the screen:

```
    def mydraw(self,the_game,scrn,realx,realy,virty,realdim):
        ...
        holder = self.bitmap.subsurface(0,self.e_y-virty,self.dim_x,self.dim_y-(self.e_y-virty))
        scrn.blit(holder,[self.x,0])
        if(self.has_next==True):
            self.next.mydraw(the_game,scrn,realx,realy,virty,realdim)
```

code that was abbreviated out is for determining if the user clicked on a slot, determining screen coordinates from scrolling coordinates, etc.

The reason for it being written like this is because: a) I expect there to be quite a lot of slots potentially for one panel. I figured drawing to a large bitmap and grabbing what I need wouldn't be smart, or scalable. b) individual slots may be deleted

I can make examples work, but not this work.  I can see the actual bitmap: self.bitmap, being drawn to the screen but no string. IDK whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated updatesprite method:

```
def updatesprite(self,the_game,font):
    self.bitmap.fill((240,240,240))
    phrase = self.wordnum
    if(self.has_phrase==True):
        phrase+=self.phrase
    text = font.render(phrase,1,(0,0,255))
    **self.bitmap.blit(text,[1, 1])** #compare to original
```

heh